# event listener on canvas in html5 issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i am new in html5 , i want to create a event listener on my mouse , i have written the following code , but cannot understand y , i cant create the event listener on my canvas element , kindly help

```
     var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvas');
     canvas_simple = document.createElement('canvas');
     canvas_simple.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
     canvas_simple.setAttribute('id', 'canvasSimple');
     canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas_simple);
     if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined')
     {
     canvas_simple = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas_simple);
     }
     context_simple = canvas_simple.getContext("2d");
    context_simple.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove, false);
```

in light of a ans i want give me event listener code also , may be it has a error also

```
  var started = false;
  function ev_mousemove (ev) {
  var x, y;

   if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
  x = ev.layerX;
  y = ev.layerY;
  } 
  else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
  x = ev.offsetX;
  y = ev.offsetY;
  }
  if (!started) {

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  started = true;
  }
  else {
    context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.stroke();
     }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the event to your canvas, not the 2d context:

```
canvas_simple.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_mousemove, false);
```

Here is a demo: [**jsFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCxcT/)

Comment: if u r rite than y my even listener is not working :s the event listener code is

Comment: var started = false;
  function ev_mousemove (ev) {
    var x, y;

    // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
      if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
      x = ev.layerX;
      y = ev.layerY;
      } 
   else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
      x = ev.offsetX;
      y = ev.offsetY;
      }

    // The event handler works like a drawing pencil which tracks the mouse 
    // movements. We start drawing a path made up of lines.
      if (!started) {

Comment: context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(x, y);
      started = true;
      }
   else {
  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.lineWidth = 10;
        context.lineTo(x, y);
        context.stroke();
         }
  }

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you: I hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/gCxcT/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes:

- You cannot attach the listener to the context, listeners can only be attached to: a single node in a document, the document itself, a window, or an XMLHttpRequest. So you should attach it to the canvas element.
- You cannot nest canvas
- The canvasHeight property is not defined

I created a jsfiddle with your example modified and working --> [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m9UF3/1/)

Comment: well , you got right , what my code is trying to do is color where ever my mouse moves on the canvas , but the issue is only some part of my screen is active i-e canvas is colored !

Comment: what do you mean only some part of the screen is active?

Comment: i mean is , color was only done on specific region, not the whole canvas , any how i solved it thanks alot for your help , i hope i could also give you a vote