# html5 canvas obj.addEventListener is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to click a canvas and get the mouse position, similar to [Getting mouse location in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114465/getting-mouse-location-in-canvas).

```
var board = new function(){
    this.id = document.getElementById("board");
    this.ctx = this.id.getContext("2d");
}

function newGame(piece) {
    drawGrid();
    board.addEventListener("click", getMousePosition);
    if (piece == "X") {
        players.player = "X";
        players.computer = "O";
    } else {
        players.player = "O";
        players.computer = "X";
    }
}
```

I've been racking my brain and the internet trying to solve the issue. There's [Cannot attach Event listener to canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343331/cannot-attach-event-listener-to-canvas) but I'm not using getElementsByTagName. I looked at [MouseMove issue on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879622/mousemove-issue-on-canvas), but my canvas shouldn't be out of scope the way I defined it. [event listener on canvas in html5 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337759/event-listener-on-canvas-in-html5-issue) doesn't help because I'm not trying to add a listener to the context. Could someone please tell me what's going on?

https://codepen.io/csinclair/pen/owVqyq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is board.id, not board.

should be 
    `board.id.addEventListener("click", getMousePosition);`